# Django javascript problem after postback

Tags: jquery, django, postback, onload

I have two radio buttons, one combo and one textbox in my form field. Combobox is hidden/shown depending on radio buttons selection and textbox is required field. I also want to radio1 is default selected.
I show and hide the combobox like

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#radio1').bind('click',onRadioChange);
    $('#radio2').bind('click',onRadioChange);
    $('#combo').parent().parent().hide();
            $('#radio1').click();
}

function onRadioChange(){
        if($('#radio1').is(':checked'))
            $('#combo').parent().parent().slideDown("fast");
        else
            $('#combo').parent().parent().slideUp("fast");
}
```

It works normal when page load at first but if I post the form with empty `textbox` it gives error and this time (although click events are binded) `combo` is not hidden.

Besides, if I click the `Radio2` before posting the form, I would expect that it comes as selected after the postback. However, javascript works on load and change the selected radio as natural.

How can I manage this kind of postback problems in django ?

Thanks

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with django. If you get a javascript-error, all following javascript-code is not executed. You should debug your code using e.g. firebug. And if you posted some more of your code, it would be easier to help you.